# Where to store client_id and client_secret in Oauth2?

Tags: spring, authentication, oauth-2.0, github-api

I would like to bring a login with `Github` and `Facebook` to my single page web app, the server is under my control.

In this tutorial
https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/
they store the `client_id` and `client_secret` in a file.

Wouldn't it be more convenient if I stored these 2 in my backend database ? 
Let's say someone who's not a programmer would like to register the web app to a new service , he could do that easily opening the `database`, he doesn't have to crawl into the backend project code.

If not then where should these 2 be stored ?

Comment: yes you must store clientID and clientSecret in DB. They just represent your single page web app in facebook and used to generate access token and this access token will use by users with their user name and password of facebook.

Comment: so the tutorial where they stored these 2 pieces of information in a file, is just an example and not really a practical one ?

Comment: I would like to disagree with @AnuragDadheech's comment. I know of multiple production systems where the creds are stored in a property file. Mostly because of the convenience. The only thing is that there are different property files for different environments. Say application-dev.properties, application-stating.properties. The default application.properties is used for production systems.

Comment: Okay i agree @Yashin but what about security?? And what would be the step when client ID and Client secret needs to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you talk about the convenience, storing these in a property file is a good option. By doing so, the properties can be easily loaded into the application during the startup. If you change the values, all you need to do is just restart the app and the new values will be reflected.

I am not sure I understand your non-programmer related comment 100%. But IMO, for a non-programmer, modifying a file is much easier than modifying the DB.

Just to be more clear, the client id and the client secret represents the credentials of your application registered with the social media (like facebook).

Ans yes, you can store these in DB as well. But then, you need to write code to fetch these values from the DB and load into your application.

Comment: about the non programmer, I would like to ask if there is a way where I could write code which handle any type of social login , because in this tutorial there is separate java code handling github and facebook , so when I want to register my web app to a new service like news then this means that I have to add new code to my backend server. And this seems like pain to me. (I'm doing this for the first time so it's not quite obvious to me what to do :)

Comment: So, irrespective of where you store the credentials, you will have to write the additional code to support the additional social media. I can't think of any possible way where you just add the additional credentials and everything works fine. If it is a pain, that means you are improving :)